# MySQL DATE_SUB Birthday Select Satement

Tags: mysql, date, select

I am writing a script to select all people from a database with a birthday 7 days early and send them an e-mail

I can select all people with birthdays for today but I need to subtract 7 days so i can send the e-mail in advance. I have tried several uses of `Date_Sub` with no Success.

here is the code I am using now.

```
select
  name, 
  email, 
  birthday 
from members 
where 
  month(birthday) = month(now()) 
  and dayofmonth(birthday) = dayofmonth(now());
```

How can I subtract 7 days from the date? I am using Mysql

Answer (score 2):

```
select
  name, 
  email, 
  birthday 
from members 
where 
  month(birthday) = month(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)) 
  and dayofmonth(birthday) = dayofmonth(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK));
```

Comment: Nice! Deleted mine as it was TSQL.

Comment: I believe DATE_SUB should be DATE_ADD in your answer.